# Multiple windows in Qdockwidets with Qt

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I'm having some trouble creating a interface with Qt. i'd like to have a dock like the one in Qt Designer (cf below): Multiple subwindows that closable (or minimisable).

I found things like MainWindow::tabifyDockWidget but that's not exactacly what i'm looking for.

Does someone know how to make it ?

thx.

Comment: I've got an example here : http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/117001_118000/117474.png (the right and the left dock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself :

```
QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(tr("Histogramme"), this);
histogram = new QWidget;
dock->setWidget(histogramme);
ui->menuWindow->addAction(dock->toggleViewAction());
```

A new dock must be created for each new "subwindow".